# Vector only contains one element

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, jsoncpp

I'm making a Text Adventure in C++ as an attempt to learn the language. The player interacts using commands like *look* or *travel north*. So far I've got code that converts the text to lowercase and then splits it into a Vector. This works fine for one word commands, but when I go to implement longer commands I find that the length always = 1 and accessing over that returns in an error. Here's my code:

```
//Input function.
void Input() {
    const char delim = ' ';

    //Processing
    std::cin >> input;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    std::vector<std::string> out;
    split(input, ' ', out);

    //Commands
    if (out[0] == "exit")
        exit(0);
    else if (out[0] == "help")
        Help();
    else if (out[0] == "look")
        Look();
    else if (out[0] == "travel" || out[0] == "go") {
        //This code will never run.
        if (int(out.size()) == 2) {
            Travel(out[1]);
        }
    }
}

//Split function
void split(std::string const& str, const char delim, std::vector<std::string>& out)
{
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(ss, s, delim)) {
        out.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Any help would be vastly appreciated!
Thanks, Logan.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's possible to pass `std::tolower` directly to `std::transform`, the lambda isn't needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fun fact, when you do this:

```
std::cin >> input;
```

It reads characters up until the next whitespace character, and puts those into the string. That means `input` will only contain the first word you entered.

Want to get the whole line? Well, clearly, you already know how to do that, just call `std::getline`:

```
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```